# What do you call philosophical statements that you can prove mathematically or by other means?

Tags: terminology

What do you call philosophical statements that you can prove mathematically or by other means? I thought theorem was a word for it, but it doesn't seem the case, so do we just use assertions as a replacement for the word theorem, which seems to be only used in mathematics? I am still wondering if this is correct, because mathematics also deals with logic.

Comment: Mathematical logic uses the term theorem if a statement is provable in a system of reasoning. You may also want to look into the term lemma. You use the word assertion which is problematic at least in philosophy. Is it an assertion because you don't know whether the statement is true or not? If it is assertion because you are unaware of the value then it magically becomes true with evidence? Before the evidence the claim was true. Propositions are deemed true or false objectively whether you are aware of it or have evidence. An assumption is the case where you don't know the value & you pick 1

Comment: "Thesis" isn't philosophy-specific but is comparable to "theorem," here. "Doctrine" could also be an option. Another way to look at it is to say that philosophy doesn't conclude in answers so much as riddles, puzzles, paradoxes, questions... By erotetic inference, then, we might speak of *problems* themselves, when appropriately produced, as the counterparts, in philosophy, of theorems.

Comment: There are no philosophical statements that one can prove mathematically. Philosophical statements are conceptual interpretations, so they are over and above what mathematics and logic can provide. Philosophers talk about theses and arguments or defenses of them, not theorems and proofs, and the reasoning involved isn't formal or deductive.